# AVAudioPlayer Not playing Mp3 File I tried But no luck

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Hi I am using below code to play my local mp3 file. but no error came. but mp3 is not playing.

```
AVAudioPlayer  *audioPlayer ;
NSString *sound_file;
if ((sound_file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mpthreetest" ofType:@"mp3"])){

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:sound_file];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;


    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];

}
```

Comment: NSBundle has a method called URLForResource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Following steps.

1. Your AppDelegate.m

   ```
   #import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>`<AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>
   ```
2. Your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   {
       self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
       self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
   }
   ```
3. In Your ViewController.h

   ```
   @property (nonatomic,retain) AVAudioPlayer  *audioPlayer ;
   ```
4. In Your ViewController.m

   ```
   @synthesize audioPlayer;
   ```

Then

```
NSString *sound_file;
if ((sound_file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mpthreetest" ofType:@"mp3"])){

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:sound_file];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;

    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];    
}
```

The mistake you did is that you did not set Property.